# Jquery does not recognize selector passed from an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to pass, categories names from an array to a jquery selector and manipulate the css and after doing some animations.

i had problems with double strings, but i fix them, but now whetever i do it gives me error.

Here is the error:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .cat-cloths_&_clothing`

The output of the array is:

`["cloths_&clothing", "old&_new_home", "food_rituals", "assorted", "route_to_freedom", "artworks", "road_movement"]`

My code is:

```
var categorieGr = PostsArray.groupBy('category');
console.log(categorieGr);
var catNamesNoParse = Object.keys(categorieGr);
var catNames = [];
for (i = 0; i < catNamesNoParse.length; i++) {
    catNames.push(JSON.parse(catNamesNoParse[i]));
}
console.log(catNames);
var menu_cat_name;
for (var i = 0; i < catNames.length; i++) {
    $("#cat-menu ul").append('<li id="cat-' + catNames[i] + '"><span class="tab">' + catNames[i].replace(/\_/g, ' ').toUpperCase() + '</span></li>');
}

var selected_cat

$("#cat-menu ul li").click(function () {
    CatSelect = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < catNames.length; i++) {
        console.log(catNames[i])
        $("." + "cat-" + catNames[i]).css("background-color", "");
    }
```

Comment: class name can't contain `~ ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) + = , . / ' ; : " ? > < [ ] \ { } | `` #`

Comment: That was easy, thanks a lot.